# Integer token using flex and yacc

Tags: compiler-errors, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

I am trying to identify an integer token using flex and yacc. This is my flex file syntax for integers.

```
%{
#include "main.h"
#include "y.tab.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define YYSTYPE char *
void yyerror(char *);
%}

code            "code"
special         ":"
turn            "turn"
send            "send"
on              "on"
pin             "pin"
for             "for"
num             "[0-9]+"

%%
{code}          {return CODE;}
{special}       {return SPECIAL; }
{turn}          {return OPRTURN;}
{send}          {return OPRSEND;}
{on}            {return OPRON;}
{pin}           {return PORT;}
{for}           {return FOR;}
{num}           { yylval.iValue = atoi(yytext); return INTEGER;}
%%

int yywrap(void) {
return 1;
}
```

in yacc file..

```
%{
    #include "main.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdarg.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
//    char *name[10];

void  startCompiler();

/* prototypes */
nodeType *enm(char* c);
nodeType *opr(int oper,int nops,...);
nodeType *id(int i);
nodeType *con(int value);
nodeType *cmd(char *c);

void freeNode(nodeType *p);
int ex(nodeType *p);
int yylex(void);

void yyerror(char *s);
//int sym[26];                    /* symbol table */
%}

%union {
    int iValue;                 /* integer value */
    char sIndex;                /* symbol table index */
    char *str;                /* symbol table index */
    nodeType *nPtr;             /* node pointer */
};

%token <iValue> INTEGER

%token CODE SPECIAL OPRTURN OPRSEND OPRON PORT FOR
%type <nPtr> stmt stmt_list oper operation duration pin location



%%

input   : function { exit(0);}
        ;

input   : function { exit(0);}
        ;

function : function stmt  { ex($2); freeNode($2);}
        |
        ;

stmt    : 

        | PORT location          { printf("Port taken"); }
        ;


location : INTEGER  { printf("Number is %d",$1); }

                ;
```

but when I execute the program, it does not recognize the number,

Input is

> pin 4

Output

> 4

Output should be

> Port taken Number is 4

What am I missing here?
All the other tokens are working fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post enough code to run the code and reproduce the problem. Also be more clear about what the input, actual output and expected output. Is the input "pin 4" and the output "4"? And the expected output would be "Number taken" and nothing else?

Comment: @sepp2k I have added the full codes.
actually what I need to identify is my code gets `pin 4` and identify pin and number. Then I can use that number for further processing in my C code.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what your input, actual output and expected output are. I don't see how the output can just be `4`, there's nothing in your code that just prints a number without additional text.

Comment: @sepp2k here what I want to do is, when input is given as `pin 4` my grammar should identifiy it and `Port taken Number is 4`.
This is just  fragment of a large code, I am trying to make a pseudo code into an arduino code.

Comment: Okay and what does happen? Because looking at the code, that's exactly what I'd expect to happen.

Comment: @sepp2k when `pin 4` input is given, it just output `4`, not `Port taken number 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you get is the output from the `yyerror` function, which by default just prints invalid tokens to stderr.

What happens is that "pin" is properly recognized, but "4" isn't. So the statement rule isn't producing any output because it's still waiting for an integer. So the only output is that of `yyerror`.

The reason it doesn't recognize 4 is that you quoted the regex for numbers as a string literal. So it's looking for the literal string "[0-9]+". Remove the quotes to have it be interpreted as a regex.

PS: You'll also want to add a rule that skips whitespace or else you'll have to input `pin4` without spaces.

Comment: Yes, That was my mistake. Thanks a lot @sepp2k